# How to read specific words in text file using Python

Tags: python

Say I have a text file and inside is the following:

```
Hello my name is John.
```

Using the Python function for reading

```
data = open("test.txt", "r")
print("data.readline(2 - 4))
```

How to I read only from the second character (e) to the fourth (l). So when I run the program it prints "ell"

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
f.seek(1)
print(f.read(3))
```

`seek(1)` is move to position of the first byte in file, and `read(3)` is read the following 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line[1:4])
```

Comment: It doesn't work it give me a syntax error at row 3, column 17

Comment: This is Python 3; `print()` should be used as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read()` method to do it like this:

```
data = open("test.txt", "r")
print(data.read(4)[1:])
```

Comment: The question suggests that OP is using Python 3, so print should be a function.

Comment: I am using Python 3.3